# Mapping HAL URI in @RequestBody to a Spring Data Rest managed entity

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am using Spring Data JPA to manage a JPA entity and Spring Data Rest exports the repository into a REST API.

I am also building a custom controller where I want to take the URI of the entity (HAL link) and automatically map it to entity object via the `CrudRepository`.

CustomController

```java
@RequestMapping(path = MeLinks.ELEVATE, method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = RestMediaTypes.TEXT_URI_LIST_VALUE)
HttpEntity<?> elevate(@RequestBody @Valid CollectionModel<Contact> contact) {
    ...
}
```

When trying to `PUT` a contact link like `http://localhost:8080/contacts/1` with Content-Type `text/uri-list`, I am able to access the link using `contact.getLinks()` but not the Contact object itself.

Is it possible for Spring Data Rest to automatically infer the entity from the URI? I am aware of an in-built `UriToEntityConverter` but how do I use it?

*Edit*

Here is an attempt that works but doesn't really solve the problem gracefully.

Below code initializes a `UriToEntityConverter` and converts the incoming URI to domain object.

```java
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private MappingContext<?, ?> mappingContext;

@RequestMapping(path = MeLinks.ELEVATE, method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = RestMediaTypes.TEXT_URI_LIST_VALUE)
HttpEntity<?> elevate(@RequestBody @Valid CollectionModel<Contact> uris) {

    URI uri = URI.create(uris.getLinks().get(0).getHref());

    Repositories repositories = new Repositories(applicationContext);

    PersistentEntity<?,?> contactPersistentEntity = repositories.getPersistentEntity(Contact.class);

    UriToEntityConverter uriToEntityConverter = new UriToEntityConverter(
        new PersistentEntities(Collections.singleton(mappingContext)), 
        new DefaultRepositoryInvokerFactory(repositories), 
        repositories);

    Contact t = (Contact) uriToEntityConverter.convert(uri, TypeDescriptor.valueOf(URI.class), TypeDescriptor.valueOf(Contact.class));
}
```

As you can imagine, fetching the domain object from the `Repository` would be much easier than doing above. Also this works assuming the URI uses the `ID` as unique part of the link. In my case I have customized it to use a UUID instead. So default behaviour of `UriToEntityConverter` would not work.

NOTE: `Resources` class [has been renamed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/etc/migrate-to-1.0.sh#L95) to `CollectionModel` with HATEOAS first release.

Comment: Works for me, but too bad it doesn't work for child entities (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/contacts/1/childEntity`) I searched around and found nothing so far.

Comment: @GuiRitter what doesn't work for child entities exactly? Does child entity also have a repository or is it a custom link? In case of custom link, are you using a `RepositoryRestController`?

Comment: In the example link above, it tries to parse `childEntity` as a `Long`, as if it were a `contact` id I suppose. `childEntity` does have a repository but no custom link.

Comment: Ah I see. This could be because `UriToEntityConverter` is meant to parse only root URIs. So in your case the URI to parse should be `http://localhost:8080/child_entities/1` or similar.

Comment: Im trying to use your code, but how do you get @Autowired
private MappingContext<?, ?> mappingContext;?

Comment: Autowiring MappingContext<?, ?> works for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using the `UriToEntityConverter` I recommend checking out [this part of the Spring Data REST documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr) to customize the resource URI to a different property by using the `EntityLookupSupport<T>` class. The `UriToEntityConverter` should then return the entity correctly.

If you wish to use the repository directly as you stated consider the following:

Looking at the source code of [`UriToEntityConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/UriToEntityConverter.java#L126), it uses the last part of the URI as the identifier of the object. You could do this too. (In this code snippet I have just modified your code from above, assuming that you correctly retrieve the `URI` object)

```
private ContactRepository contactRepository;

// You should use constructor injection, as it is preferred over field injection.
@Autowired
public CustomController(ContactRepository contactRepository){
    this.contactRepository = contactRepository;
}


@RequestMapping(path = MeLinks.ELEVATE, method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = RestMediaTypes.TEXT_URI_LIST_VALUE)
HttpEntity<?> elevate(@RequestBody @Valid CollectionModel<Contact> uris) {
    URI uri = URI.create(uris.getLinks().get(0).getHref());

    Optional<Contact> optionalContact = contactRepository.findByName(getLastUriPart(uri));

    if (optionalContact.isPresent()){
        return optionalContact.get();
    } else {
        // Error handling
    }
}

private String getLastUriPart(URI uri) {
    String[] uriParts = uri.getPath().split("/");

    if (uriParts.length < 2) {
        // Error handling
    }

    return uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified the instantiating of UriToEntityConverter as part of a service with auto-wired dependencies.

This worked for me:

```
@Service
public class UriToEntityConversionService {

    private UriToEntityConverter converter;

    @Autowired
    public UriToEntityConversionService(PersistentEntities entities, RepositoryInvokerFactory invokerFactory,
                                        Repositories repositories) {
        converter = new UriToEntityConverter(entities, invokerFactory, repositories);
    }

    public <T> T convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType){
        return (T) converter.convert(source, sourceType, targetType);
    }

}
```

calling it in my custom controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/processes/{id}/protocols", method = { PUT, POST }, consumes = {TEXT_URI_LIST_VALUE})
    HttpEntity<?> overrideLinkProtocolsDefaultEndpoint(@PathVariable("id") Process process,
                                             @RequestBody Resources<Object> incoming,
                                             PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) throws URISyntaxException {
    // TODO handle both PUT and POST and all links
    URI uri = new URI(incoming.getLinks().get(0).getHref());
    Protocol protocol = uriToEntityConversionService.convert(uri, TypeDescriptor.valueOf(URI.class), TypeDescriptor.valueOf(Protocol.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (@RequestBody EntityModel) in parameters of @RepositoryRestController

For example

```
fun createPendingPayment(@RequestBody bookingEntityModel: EntityModel<Booking>): ResponseEntity<PendingPayment>
```

then you can use links in the requestBody like this

```
{
    "restaurant": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/restaurants/1",
    "date":"2022-02-26",
    "time":"11:00",
    "member": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/members/1",
    "persons": 3,
    "status": "CONFIRMED",
    "payment": "FULL"
}
```